# ezpdf php using 100% cpu usage

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I have a question.  I am using `class.ezpdf.php` to create a PDF that I am pulling up on my browser.   This PDF is made up of events, which are items that are detected by snort.   I am listing certain criteria for each event.   When the amount of the events gets into the thousands, the PDF ends up not being created.

It will sit there for a minute or 2, then will instead of opening the PDF, it will ask if I want to open or save the php file I am using to create the PDF, but the file is empty.  The PDF is never created.  In the meantime, I have run the `top` command on my box and I can see while this is trying to process, the process `php.fcgi` is using 100% cpu.

Even after the save/open box comes up for grabbing the php file and I close this box, it continues to show 100% is being used for several minutes.  It seems that I have to close my browser that was running that script for it to release this process.  I am at a loss on what to do.  There used to be a perl script that did the same thing in regards to taking the events and putting them into a PDF, however this issue did not exist, even for a PDF that would contain this number of events.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> It will sit there for a minute or 2, then will instead of opening the PDF, it will ask if I want to open or save the php file I am using to create the PDF, but the file is empty. The PDF is never created. In the meantime, I have run the top command on my box and I can see while this is trying to process, the process php.fcgi is using 100% cpu.

It sounds like the web server you are using is timing out while waiting for the FastCGI process to give it a response.  It's probably giving you whatever data might be present -- the headers causing a download, in this case -- then just closing the connection.

You will need to consult your web server documentation to find the FastCGI timeout and increase it as needed.

Comment: thank you for the information, we are using a zeus server, i will try to look in the documentation to see if there is a way to change this.

Comment: also, by increasing this timeout, do you know if this will cause any problems or have any negative effect

Comment: @Josh, I'm so incredibly sorry about Zeus.  I hadn't realized that they were still even around.  Good luck.  Increasing the timeout alone should not have any side effects other than, well, increasing how long it might take *bad* requests to time out.

Comment: i looked in the manual for zeus, but was not able to find a time out setting.   I am going on their message board to see if i can find out an answer, by offchance, you would not happen to know Charles.  Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: @Josh, I consider Zeus to be bad software.  For years they had *horrible* Perl and PHP support.  It made my life as a commercial software developer pure hell any time one of our customers was stuck behind their server software.  Other than the fact that they sucked, I know very little about it.  That and they seem to have put all their documentation behind a paywall.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help with what you were able to provide.  I appreciate it.

Comment: i was able to find documentation on increasing this time out, but I was also reading about possibly having my php script send a request to the client every so often, so that the web server does not time out, trying to determine what i could use to do that

Comment: @Josh, while that process works for normal HTML output -- you can just send a comment tag down the line or something -- it won't work well when you're trying to produce specific output for a download.  Another thing you might consider is using a work queue like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) to actually build the PDF in the background, polling the worker occasionally via ajax to determine the status.  Once that's done, you can give them a link to their constructed document.  It might take one more click, but it'd avoid the timeout problem.